# IB_DESIGNABLE, having views show in preview?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have my views showing in interface builder with my `IB_DESIGNABLE` properties set, however when I use the preview feature to see how my views look on various devices, I just get the super view name, e.g. `UIView`.

Don't `IB_DESIGNABLE` views show in preview?

EDIT As requested code + screen shot:

```
H
=
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface TitleBannerView : UILabel
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat borderWidth;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat cornerRadius;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat shadowHeight;
@end

M
=
@implementation TitleBannerView
@synthesize borderWidth;
@synthesize cornerRadius;
@synthesize shadowHeight;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    if (self.borderWidth == 0) self.borderWidth = 8.5;
    if (self.cornerRadius == 0) self.cornerRadius = 33;
    if (self.shadowHeight == 0) self.shadowHeight = 15.1;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* bG = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.18 green: 0.8 blue: 0.443 
       alpha: 1];
    UIColor* borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.557 green: 0.267 blue: 0.678 
       alpha: 1];
    UIColor* shadowColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.976 green: 0.859 blue: 0.718 
       alpha: 1];

    //// Shadow Declarations
    UIColor* shadow = shadowColor2;
    CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-4.1, self.shadowHeight);
    CGFloat shadowBlurRadius = 1.5;
```

//

```
    //// Frames
    CGRect frame = self.bounds;

    //// Subframes
    CGRect group = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 15, 
        CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 15, CGRectGetWidth(frame) - 28, 
        CGRectGetHeight(frame) - 40);


    //// Abstracted Attributes
    CGFloat roundedRectangleStrokeWidth = self.borderWidth ;
    CGFloat roundedRectangleCornerRadius = self.cornerRadius;

    //// Group
    {
        //// Rounded Rectangle Drawing
        UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: 
           CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(group) + floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.00060) + 0.5, 
           CGRectGetMinY(group) + floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.00568) + 0.5, 
          floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.99940) - floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.00060), 
         floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.99432) - floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.00568)) 
         cornerRadius: roundedRectangleCornerRadius];
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius, 
            shadow.CGColor);
        [bG setFill];
        [roundedRectanglePath fill];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        [borderColor setStroke];
        roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = roundedRectangleStrokeWidth;
        [roundedRectanglePath stroke];

    }
}
@end
```

The TitleBannerView is the view in green with purple border.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean  you use @IBDesignable to specify your view's properties instead of your view?

Comment: No I don't see the drawings I create within drawrect on the preview.

Comment: Does it work on simulator?

Comment: Yes and in interface builder

Answer (score 3):

First, IBDesignable can be visible in preview.

Do you declare your IBDesignable class in a framework? IBInspectable ONLY supports preview when it's declared in a framework.

Also, keep in mind (not in your case):

1. Your draw code should be fast enough, you only have 100ms draw time for an item.
2. prepareForInterfaceBuilder() method is often needed.

Comment: I don't currently have my drawing classes in a framework I'll try that and post back

Comment: If you really don't, it should be the most possible reason. Good luck.

Comment: Just tested it and it really does render. How did I miss this? How did you discover it? :)

Comment: The same problem occurred to me when swift released. At the moment, using @IBDesignable randomly work or not if it's declared not in a framework so I try to find the reason out. I'm not sure where I found it, most likely from apple's developer forum.

Comment: @Jules File -> New -> Target, select Cocoa Touch Framework, drag any IBDesignable classes to the newly created folder, then in the file inspector (cmd + alt + 1) under Target Membership, check your framework for .h files and select Public from the drop down, then uncheck your main target and also check your framework for .m files.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some mock data to display in interface builder?

When you use @ `IBDesignable` Your initializers, layout, and drawing methods will be used to render your custom view right on the canvas

Since the custom view won’t have the full context of your app when rendered in Interface Builder, you may need to generate mock data for display, such as a default user profile image or generic weather data. There are two ways to add code for this special context

- `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`: This method compiles with the rest of your code but is only executed when your view is being prepared for display in Interface Builder.
- TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER: The `#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER` preprocessor macro will work in either Objective-C or Swift to conditionally compile the right code for the situation

You might want to take a look on this [tutorial](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) and example

Comment: In my drawrect method I check for zero values and assign some defaults

Comment: @Istvsn that should be fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: What values? Do you set up some colors as well? What you want to see on the canvas? Post some code pls

Comment: No colours, I should at least see filled areas, here's some code... - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { if (self.borderWidth == 0) self.borderWidth = 8.5;

Comment: update your question with the initializers, layout, and drawing methods please

Answer (score 1):

`IBDesignable` works only in Interface Builder, but not in preview :-(
I hope Apple fix it in new Xcode...

Comment: Do you have a source ?

Comment: Hum, all of my custom controls is displayed correctly in Interface Builder, but not in the Preview

Comment: Maybe answer from @MatthewLuiHK works, I didn't check yet