# Interface Builder PREVIEW using IBDesignable and core graphics (drawrect)?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have lots of views - sub classes (UILabel, UIVIew, UIButton etc) using core graphics (within drawrect).

These show fine within normal interface builder.

However they do not show in the `preview` assistant editor for the storyboard (where you can see how views should look on actual devices).

I've been doing some research and found posts suggesting `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` should be used. However this doesn't show in preview for me.

I asked this question some years ago, [IB_DESIGNABLE, having views show in preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479391/ib-designable-having-views-show-in-preview/33663143) however I can't reproduce this, I'm not convinced it did work back then either.

I'm still following the same approach, with a framework and that link shows my implementation.

I know that `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` should be used to do something different, to show something basic. Therefore I believe that core graphics won't work.

However, I can't even get a simple change in background color to work in the preview, although it does work in normal interface builder.

I would like to know if this is a bug (that core graphics can not be used in preview) or still a limitation in xcode?

At the very least I'd like to do something simple (like a change in background color). I have a lot of views and an impossible task to make auto layout changes.

Previously I was producing lots of screen shots, different devices, languages etc (via automation) just so I could see my auto layout changes, which is really slow way to work.

Answer (score -1):

I can verify this is a long standing bug. Apple doesn't care. Custom view be damned. All those dollars spent for more broken Xcode functionality.

Android?

Daniel

Comment: Shuuuuuu I wouldn’t go that far 

Comment: Xcode is free. It's $99 a year to distribute iOS apps in any number; free to develop. Apple doesn't care? You'll get my vote on this one if you're talking about their developer support; otherwise, not so much. Android? Be my guest... Regardless, this isn't an answer; it's a gripe. I feel you, though.